# MLM Tree structure In codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table called tbl_user

I am using codeigniter and mysql.

[image]

I need to get users list invited by using my code.

Example:I if send my code as 1235 then I should get users C,D

Note:I don't the maximum level it can go.

```
$result = $this->db->select('user_key,user_id,user_name')->from('tbl_user')->where(array('inviter_code'=>$code))->get()->result();
        $employee = array();
        foreach($result as $data){
            $emp = array();
            $emp['user_key']=$data->user_key;
            $emp['user_name']=$data->user_name;
            array_push($employee,$emp);
        }
        return $employee;
```

I had a function

```
getusers($code);
```

which will return me a list of users.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `if send my code as 1235 then I should get users C,D` can you explain the logic

Comment: Because User C is invited by code 1235 and User D is invited by user C.

Comment: what will be the result for 1234

Comment: result of 1234 would be B,C and D. Because B is invited by A and C is Invited by B and D is invited by C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to perform this MLM concept is you have to store the parent id in that new users

for my question this will be the structure of tbl_user.

[redefined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYVlc.png)

Now we can simply get number of users by performing FIND_IN_SET in mysql

This will save lot of codings and memory size

Thank you